# What are the imap search command operators supported by outlook?

Tags: office365, imap

I am trying to use imap search command with outlook but a lot of search operators are not working.

I have tried following operators:

- SINCE
- SUBJECT
- OR
- NOT

But when I tried KEYWORD operator it gives me an error. Is there a way to use outlook inbox raw query directly in outlook imap search command as can be gone in gmail imap via extension X-GM-RAW operator?